# Ищу библиотеку для работы с json в которой можно обращаться к элементам с помощью []

Tags: java, json, поиск-библиотек

Существует ли библиотека **JSON**, в которой можно обращаться к элементам с помощью `[]`

Пример

```
array["data"]
```

Comment: Ваш пример JSON не верный. JSON всегда, имеет ключ-значение. Вот вам [источник](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). Так что, видимо, ответ, нет

Comment: зачем переносить js в java?

Answer (score 3):

То что вы написали:

```
array["data"]
```

В *java* является не валидным синтаксисом. При всем желании нельзя реализовать подобное, т.к. переопредления операторов в *java* нет.

Для работы с `json` есть много библиотек имеющих различный по удобству *api*.

Например `org.json`

```
new JSONObject()
            .put("name", "Tom")
            .put("surname", "Jefferson").toString()
```